# Is there a way to add a string into a Vector but only if it doesn´t exist already? ->C++

Tags: c++, vector

I am trying to print a database using OOP in c++. But in my file.csv there are a lot of similar elements, so I'm trying to print each name only once. I know this is vague, but for you experts, this is an easy one. If possible please use basic coding.

Comment: Maybe you should use a hash_map not a vector to store those strings, or if you must, you can use a hash_map for checking work before you put that string into you Vector.

Comment: Use `std::unordered_set` instead of `std::vector`.

Answer (score 2):

If you are not limited to `vector`, use `unordered_set` to populate the data. This is implemented using a hash table. A sample program looks like below.

```
#include <unordered_set>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main() {
   unordered_set <string> data; 
   data.insert("code1");
   data.insert("code2");
   //duplicate
   data.insert("code2");

   cout << "\nAll elements : "; 
   unordered_set<string> :: iterator itr; 
   for (itr = data.begin(); itr != data.end(); itr++) 
       cout << (*itr) << endl;
   return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can insert some sql statement in your c++ code to filter out similar elements in your database before you store/use it in your program. Take a look at this page [How can i insert values into database(mySql) using cpp program?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40759004/how-can-i-insert-values-into-databasemysql-using-cpp-program) and this page https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_where.asp

Without database, this may help you [Filter out duplicate values in array in C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47469728/filter-out-duplicate-values-in-array-in-c)

Comment: and only using c++??

Comment: just get and store all the data to an link-list/ array then use a for-loop to loop the link-list with self-defined if statements to filter the data you want